# How join Row in one table mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, join, self-join

How join row in one table if row in table like this

NAME TABLE1

```
id uid uid1  name qty  price status
1  002 null  null null null  order
2  002 03002 abc  null 10000 cart
3  002 null abc  8    10000 finish
```

and get 1 row from output join like this

```
3  002 03002 abc 8 10000 finish
```

*primary the last record

thank you

Comment: A join is between two or more tables.  Are you looking for the PHP code to select data from MySQL?

Comment: You can use join to get data from multiple tables

Comment: You mean `SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;`? What does this have to do with joining?

Comment: @user2182349 yes if any php code can get the output like this. i think the mysql select can get the output like the example.

Comment: @user2182349 sory joining i mean like grouping by.

Answer (score 0):

USE SELECT  FROM  WHERE  IS NOT NULL ORDER BY

```
SELECT DISTINCT (

  SELECT uid FROM test WHERE uid IS NOT NULL ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) a_uid, 
(SELECT uid1 FROM test WHERE uid1 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) a_uid1,
(SELECT name FROM test WHERE name IS NOT NULL ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
) a_name,
(SELECT qty FROM test WHERE qty IS NOT NULL ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
) a_qty,
(

  SELECT price FROM test WHERE price IS NOT NULL ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
) a_price,
(

  SELECT status FROM test WHERE status IS NOT NULL  ORDER BY id DESC 
  LIMIT 1
) a_status
FROM test
```

Comment: @angel's wing's :- From your example, it seems you are looking for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're actually looking to do a `JOIN`, and your question isn't quite complete and doesn't make a whole lot of sense, but regardless, give this a go and let me know what the result is.

```
select max(id) as id
, uid
, max(uid1) as uid1
, max(name) as name
, sum(qty) as qty
, max(price) as price -- or sum(price)?
, max(
CASE WHEN status="finish" THEN "3 - finish"
CASE WHEN status="cart" THEN "2 - cart"
CASE WHEN status="order" THEN "1 - order"
END
) as status -- this will give you the last step that the user reached. If there are more steps possible then this could be a problem
from TABLE1
group by uid -- assuming this is a transaction id or something?
```